# Matlab: How to get the Nth element in fibonacci sequence recursively without loops or inbuilt functions

Tags: matlab, vector, struct

I am attempting to write a recursive code that takes an input n and outputs the nth term of the Fibonacci sequence, without using any loops or any of MATLABS inbuilt functions.

for exemple:

```
fibo(6)

ans = 8
```

I am having trouble with writing the code recursively, and would really appreciate some help.

with a loop I wrote:

```
function f = fib1(n)
    if n <= 1
        f = 1;
    else
        f = fib1(n-1) + fib1(n-2);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `8` for `fib1(6)`, that means you need to start your fibonacci sequence from `n=1`. However, you code indicates that you start from `n=0`. In this case, you should use `n <=2` in your `if-else` statement, i.e.,

```
function f = fib1(n)
    if n <= 2
        f = 1;
    else
        f = fib1(n-1) + fib1(n-2);
    end
end
```

such that

```
>> fib1(6)
ans =  8
```

---

If you don't want to use any recursion, you can try the code below

```
function f = fib2(n)
  f = (((1+sqrt(5))/2)^n - ((1-sqrt(5))/2)^n)/sqrt(5);
end
```

which gives

```
>> fib2(6)
ans =  8
```